# Magento - Retrieve data from database and showing duplicate result

Tags: magento

Hi
I have created a simple module to retrieve database data, I have the code `$data = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($params[id]);` to get the table and `var_dump($data);`
to display the result, but I get duplicate result when accessing http://xxxxxxxxx/beta/index.php/cms/index/testModel/id/1

Please get the module at http://www.mediafire.com/?cj80kkhye252g1k

Why I get duplicate result?
Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're seeing a vardump of a raw model (its originalData and actual Data). Try

```
vardump($data->getData());
```

This should show only the things that you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks you, it works. How do you know that it should use the getData() method?

Comment: All Magento classes extends Varien_Object